# Gulp Error Spawn EN0ENT

Tags: node.js, compiler-errors, gulp

It is my goal to create a set of files and packages to easily share among my team. Currently I have GulpJs setup on my local Mac 10.9.2, and it compiles correctly. However, when I share my setup with my two colleagues, and they run the gulp command there is an error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:998:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:34)
```

The follow is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Name build process for responsive development frameworks",
  "author": "My Name",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "gulp": "^3.6.2",
    "gulp-compass": "^1.1.8",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^0.2.1",
    "gulp-livereload": "^1.2.0",
    "tiny-lr": "0.0.5",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.5.3",
    "gulp-minify-html": "^0.1.1",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "image-min": "^0.4.5",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^0.5.0",
    "gulp-newer": "^0.3.0"
  }
}
```

Then I have my gulpfile.js setup as such:

```
// include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util');

// include plug-ins
var compass = require('gulp-compass'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    newer = require('gulp-newer'),
    minifyHTML = require('gulp-minify-html'),
    minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    reload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    lr = require('tiny-lr'),
    server = lr();



var paths = {
    jsSrc: [
        './src/js/vendor/jquery.js',
        './src/js/vendor/fastclick.js',
        './src/js/vendor/foundation.js'
    ],
    ieJsSrc: [
        './src/js/vendor/foundation-ie/jquery.js',
        './src/js/vendor/foundation-ie/jquery.foundation.buttons.js',
        './src/js/vendor/foundation-ie/jquery.foundation.clearing.js',
        './src/js/vendor/foundation-ie/jquery.foundation.forms.js',
        './src/js/vendor/foundation-ie/jquery.foundation.reveal.js',
        './src/js/vendor/foundation-ie/jquery.foundation.tabs.js',
        './src/js/vendor/foundation-ie/jquery.foundation.tooltips.js'
    ],
    jsDst: './src/js',
    jsBuild: './build/common/js',
    imgSrc: './src/img/*',
    imgDst: './build/common/img',
    imgBgSrc: './src/img/bg/*',
    imgPhotoSrc: './src/img/photos/*',
    imgBgDst: './build/common/img/bg',
    imgPhotoDst: './build/common/img/photos',
    htmlSrc: './src/**/*.html',
    htmlDst: './build',
    scssSrc: [
            './src/_scss/utsw.scss',
            './src/_scss/utsw-ie.scss',
            './src/_scss/themes/**/*.scss'
    ],
    scssDst: './src/common/css/',
    cssMedSrc: './src/css/themes/root/*.css',
    cssMedDst: './src/root/css/',
    cssMedBuild: './build/root/css/',
    cssEaSrc: './src/css/themes/sites/early-access/*.css',
    cssEaDst: './src/sites/early-access/css',
    cssEaBuild: './build/sites/early-access/css',
    cssProSrc: './src/css/themes/profile/*.css',
    cssProDst: './src/profile/css/',
    cssProBuild: './build/profile/css/',
    cssNetSrc: './src/css/themes/intranet/*.css',
    cssNetDst: './src/intranet/css/',
    cssNetBuild: './build/intranet/css/'
};

// JS hint task
gulp.task('jshint', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.jsSrc)
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});

// minify new or changed HTML pages
gulp.task('html', function() {

  return gulp.src(paths.htmlSrc)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.htmlDst));
});

// JS concat, strip debugging and minify
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.jsSrc)
    .pipe(concat('vendor.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.jsDst))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.jsBuild));
});

gulp.task('ieScripts', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.ieJsSrc)
    .pipe(concat('ie-vendor.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.jsDst))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.jsBuild));
});

// Minify any new images
gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.imgSrc)
        .pipe(newer(paths.imgDst))
        .pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 5}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.imgDst));
});

// Minify any new images
gulp.task('bg', function() {
  // Add the newer pipe to pass through newer images only
  return gulp.src(paths.imgBgSrc)
        .pipe(newer(paths.imgBgDst))
        .pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 5}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.imgBgDst));
});

// Minify any new images
gulp.task('photos', function() {
  // Add the newer pipe to pass through newer images only
  return gulp.src(paths.imgPhotoSrc)
        .pipe(newer(paths.imgPhotoDst))
        .pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 5}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.imgPhotoDst));
});

gulp.task('compass', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.scssSrc)
        .pipe(compass({
            sass: './src/_scss',
            css: './src/css',
            image: './src/img'
        }))
        .on('error', function(err) {
            // Would like to catch the error here
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/temp'));
});

gulp.task('rootCSS', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.cssMedSrc)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssMedDst))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssMedBuild));
});

gulp.task('eaCSS', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.cssEaSrc)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssEaDst))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssEaBuild));
});

gulp.task('proCSS', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.cssProSrc)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssProDst))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssProBuild));
});

gulp.task('netCSS', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.cssNetSrc)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssNetDst))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssNetBuild));
});

// Rerun the task when a file changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    var server = reload();
    gulp.watch(paths.htmlSrc, ['html']);
    gulp.watch(paths.jsSrc, ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch(paths.ieJsSrc, ['ieScripts']);
    gulp.watch(paths.imgSrc, ['images']);
    gulp.watch(paths.imgBgSrc, ['bg']);
    gulp.watch(paths.imgPhotoSrc, ['photos']);
    gulp.watch(paths.scssSrc, ['compass']);
    gulp.watch(paths.cssMedSrc, ['rootCSS']);
    gulp.watch(paths.cssEaSrc, ['eaCSS']);
    gulp.watch(paths.cssProSrc, ['proCSS']);
    gulp.watch(paths.cssNetSrc, ['netCSS']);
    gulp.watch(['./src/*.html', './src/js/', './src/css/*.css'], function(e) {
        server.changed(e.path);
    });
});

// The default task (called when you run `gulp` from cli)
gulp.task('default', [
    'html',
    'scripts', 
    'ieScripts', 
    'images', 
    'bg',
    'photos',
    'compass',
    'rootCSS',
    'eaCSS',
    'proCSS',
    'netCSS',
    'watch'
]);
```

Any suggestions on how to get my colleagues setup using the same src and gulpfile.js would be awesome.

Comment: Do they have the same versions of everything installed, including Node, gulp (both global and local), and all the versions? Try running `npm update -g` and `npm update` on your machine, maybe they have a newer version.

Comment: It's probably multiple tasks running at once. Make sure you define tasks to go in the right order, and also, if you have asynchronous tasks, make sure to use the orchestrator's callback system

Comment: same thing is happen for me, but same script is working in mac but it throws same error in windows, don't understand why its happen to me.